# C Get my public IP address

Tags: c, networking, ip

What is the best way to get my public/global IP address in a C program? Similar questions on stack overflow all suggest scraping the output of a query to www.whatismyip.com or something similar, however that seems unreliable as they may change their format.

I would have thought I could request the public facing IP from my router, which seems to me like a more robust solution; though I don't explicitly know how to do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: There are some services that just [return the IP as a string](http://icanhazip.com), that is unlikely to change. You should consider cases where the computer is not directly connected to the internet, in that case getting the IP from the device would give you the LAN IP. So the best solution IS to request it from the internet.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered unless you specify which OS you are using.

Comment: I was hoping for a cross platform solution. However, Linux (Ubuntu) is my priority.

Comment: If you are in a LAN connected to a router you can only solve it as explained in my comment, unless you do a GET request to the routers HTTP server and request somehow the IP, but that is not a portable solution. If you want a cross platform solution what is more cross platform than asking someone that can see your actual IP what your IP is?

Comment: Thanks, @iharob. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: You can also use the [STUN protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN). It is more lightweight (if you care), and can be easier to do depending on the libraries you use (no HTTP needed).

Comment: Assuming you mean the IP address your ISP assigns to your home/work router to access the internet, you can also create a script to send yourself an email via your ISP's mail server, get that email, and parse the headers for the originating IP address, which should be the one assigned to your router.  I used to do that while traveling so I could remotely access my home network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may connect to a STUN server and obtain your external ip.

I think you can quite easily find the source code of a STUN client for your OS.

---

Assuming you're on *nix, a STUN client in c can be found here (it's the first I found):

https://github.com/node/turn-client

Download the source of: `c-stun-client-demo.c`

Compile with `$ clang c-stun-client-demo.c -o stun` (or use gcc)

As you run it `$ ./stun` it tells you

`usage: ./stun <server_ip> <server_port> <local_port>`

A list of STUN servers can be found in many ways. Googling I found this:

https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933

Let's take the first one:

`stun.l.google.com:19302`

You have the server name and the server port.
But the STUN client wants the server **address**; you can retrieve it with `nslookup`:

`$ nslookup stun.l.google.com`

returns `Address: 64.233.184.127`

so you'll invoke the program with:

`$ ./stun 64.233.184.127 19302 8888`

Ouput is

```
Main start ... 
socket opened to  64.233.184.127:19302  at local port 8888
Send data ...
Read recv ...
STUN binding resp: success !
socket closed !
ip:port = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:-13174
Main over.
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is your ip (it actually returned mine)

Ok, it works.

---

Look at the source code (it's around 120 lines), see how it works and implement its functionality into your program.

Comment: wow thank you. I'm a linux sysadmin 'till 98 and I never listened of a stun server. Thank you.